# "Callback is not a function" error while changing the Password

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, change-password

I'm implementing change password using **cognito** and **reactjs**.

`cognitoUser` is an object imported from a common file - **cognitoVariables.js**

`aToken - access token, 'Abcd@1234' - old password, 'Wxyz@5678' - new password`

When I execute it, I'm getting ***Callback is not a function*** error.
Can you help me with this?

```
cognitoUser.changePassword(atoken,'Abcd@1234', 'Wxyz@5678', function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        alert("Inside Error")
        alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }
    console.log('call result: ' + result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that its happening because, cognitoUser is a newly created object, doesn't have the properties like accesstoken etc since logged in user object and new cognitoUser object are different, though user is same.

If we try logging in again and onSuccess if we try password reset, it works perfectly.